# Как удалить знаки пунктуации (препинания) из конца строки?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, работа-с-текстом

Задача:
Из строки `Ха-ха!?` получить `Ха-ха`. Т.е. удалить только последние символы `!?`.
Мой пример делает лишнего и на выходе `Хаха`

```
import re
valids = re.sub(r"[^A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+", '', 'Ха-ха!?')
print(valids)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, направить регулярку на правильный путь..

UPD:
Вместо `!?` может быть любая комбинация символов (`!!!`, `?)`, `:)` ). Важно то, что она в конце.

Comment: попробуйте `'ёж ёж!'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Можно и без регулярок обойтись:

```
print('Ха-ха!?'.rstrip('!?'))  # 'Ха-ха'
```

Или взять набор символов из модуля `string`:

```
import string
print('Ха-ха!?'.rstrip(string.punctuation))  # 'Ха-ха'
```

`rstrip` удаляет справа, `lstrip` удаляет слева, а `strip` слева и справа

---

Или с такой регуляркой:

```
print(re.sub(r"[!?]+$", '', 'Ха-ха!?'))  # 'Ха-ха'
```

**@jfs** предложил такой вариант:

```
# pip install regex
import regex as re
print(re.sub(r'\p{P}+$', '', 'Ха-ха!?'))  # Ха-ха
```

Comment: в общем случае, много  символов могут рассматриваться пунктуацией. Вот для Unicode решение: [`regex.sub(r'\p{P}+$', '', text)` удаляет пунктуацию из текста](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11066400/4279).

Answer (score 4):

В регулярных выражениях есть символ, означающий конец строки - `$`

Попробуйте так:

```
import re
valids = re.sub(r"[^\w]*$", '', 'Ха-ха!?')
print(valids)
```

Comment: `[\w]` можно заменить на `\W`: `r"\W*$"`

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'Ха-ха!?'

print(string.strip('!?'))
```